# Fusion chart Legend Customization

Tags: angular, fusion

Currently I am using Fusion Donut 2D chart for my angular application, I am trying to customize the chart legend visualization. Below is the image for legend I am looking for.  Please share code which might be helpful for me

[image: Fusion chart with legend]

I tried this, but it's not working.

```
"chart": {
    //"caption": "Device alarm by status",
    "showToolTip":"0",
    "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
    //Theme
    "theme": "fusion",
    "legendPosition": "RIGHT",
    "numberSuffix": " <br/> ",
    "showValues": "0",
    "showLabels": "0",
    "showValueAsPercentInLegend": "0",
    "showValuesInLegend": "1",
    "showLegend":"1",
    "legendIconScale": "3",
    "drawCustomLegendIcon": "1",
    "legendIconAlpha": "100",
    "legendIconSides": "4",
    "legendIconStartAngle": "45",
    "legendXPosition": "90",
    "startingAngle": "310",
    "legendWidth": "200"
  },
```